# Change home page category block style CSS

Tags: magento-1.9

I have home page with categories showing very well but now I have to make some design related changes to show category without title and blocks with lines as box.

Current:
[image]

Desired style:
[image]
Let me guide how to change category grid layout using css

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Could you add some screenshot?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri updated

Comment: you have added this section from local.xml or any layout or in home directly please check and give us code of that file

Comment: my basic concern is to change category block layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been done by changing categories div properties inside theme styles.css file:

```
#Category-Grid .Categories {
float: left;
color: #606265;
width: 210px;
height: 249px;
padding: 0px 12px 0 12px;
margin-top: 1px;

border-style: dotted;
border-width: 0px 0px 1.9px 1.9px;
border-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```